# Login function CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I have a login function in PHP on the cake 2.7 framework that will not make it past the first `if` statement. The conditional seems to always be false and I am really confused why.  Am I not implementing the request correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Login()

```
function login() { 

if (!empty($this->request->data) && $this->Auth->user()) {

  // Delete all old tokens
  $this->Tour->recursive = -1;
  $this->Tour->deleteAll(array('Tour.userid' => $this->Auth->user('userid')));
  // Create a new token

  $this->Tour->create();
  $this->Tour->save(array('token' => md5(rand()), 'userid' => $this->Auth->user('userid')));
  // Update login count
  $user = $this->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('userid'));
  $user['User']['logincount']++;
  $this->User->saveField('logincount', $user['User']['logincount']);
  // Update last login time
  $this->User->saveField('lastlogin', date('Y-m-d h:m:s'));
  echo 'doesnt work';
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            echo 'authLogin';
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }

}
}
}
```

Comment: Please follow [my previous advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000957/beforefilter-function-breaks-cakephp#comment53845380_33000957) Your code looks nothing like [a simple login example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> that will not make it past the first if statement.

Of course it won't because of the `&& $this->Auth->user()` condition you have. Since user is not logged in `$this->Auth->user()` will return null and it won't enter the `if` block.